# 08-27 08:26:11.330: A/libc(23962): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 23962

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, error-handling, cocos2d-x

i got this error when opening my app, my app is created from cocos2dx after installing it to android phone and ope it, its give me that error

```
08-27 08:26:11.310: D/dalvikvm(23962): Trying to load lib /data/app-
lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so 0x4250e6f0
08-27 08:26:11.330: A/libc(23962): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 23962 etc.
```

its been my 2 days problem and now im loosing my hope :(
can u guys give an idea where this error came from?

backtrace

```
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2345):     #00  pc 00956180  /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (_JavaVM::GetEnv(void**, int)+28)
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2345):     #01  pc 00956548  /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::JniHelper::cacheEnv(_JavaVM*)+60)
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2345):     #02  pc 00956300  /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::JniHelper::getEnv()+80)
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2345):     #03  pc 00956a60  /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(cocos2d::JniMethodInfo_&, char const*, char const*, char const*)+88)
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2345):     #04  pc 009547f4  /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (getFileDirectoryJNI()+168)
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2345):     #05  pc 00952cd4  /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::FileUtilsAndroid::getWritablePath() const+136)
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2345):     #06  pc 006385f0  /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Console::Console()+7180)
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2345):     #07  pc 00659f28  /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Director::init()+992)
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2345):     #08  pc 00659720  /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Director::getInstance()+348)
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2345):     #09  pc 004d5f30  /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (cocos2d::Node::Node()+696)
D/CrashAnrDetector( 2345):     #10  pc 002627dc  /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (BookManager::BookManager()+28)
```

noob here, thanks

```
D/dalvikvm(22484): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.sample1.sample-1/libcocos2dcpp.so 0x42510298
V/LvOutput( 1935): initCheck: 0
V/LvOutput( 1935): detachEffects: detach processing for output 2, stream 1, session 3025
V/LvOutput( 1935): detachEffects: no output processing was attached to this stream
V/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stopOutput() output 2, stream 1, session 3025
V/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): changeRefCount() stream 1, count 0
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [13], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [14], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [13], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [14], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [13], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [14], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [13], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [14], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [13], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [14], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [13], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [14], return media strategy
V/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): getNewDevice() selected device 0
V/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): setOutputDevice() output 2 device 0000 force 0 delayMs 184 
V/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): setOutputDevice() prevDevice 0002
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [13], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [14], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [13], return media strategy
W/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): stream type [14], return media strategy
V/AudioPolicyManagerBase( 1935): setOutputDevice() setting same device 0000 or null device for output 2
I/Mms/MmsApp(22428):  start initViewCache mms
F/libc    (22484): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 22484 (sample1.sample)
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you have call java code by cocos2d,you need make your java code run run on ui Thread

Comment: thanks, but i didnt call it from cocos2d, i dont know where that error came from, that error happened in my last code update in ios(nothing to do with java codes) and now im stack on that

Comment: found out that my friend instantiate like this SampleManager* m_sampleManager = SampleManager::getInstance(); near the include area or declaration area, (don't know the rigth term, sorry) its working in ios but not in android. noob here ^_^

Comment: i mean at the declaration area :D